# Cross-Browser solution to hide/style a scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, scrollbar

im working on a website system its dynamic with javascript/jquery/ajax so i dont know the actual layout size of the content div `<div id="content"></div>`

id like to style the scrollbar or at least hide it but i cant find any solution that works for every browser.

Does someone know a possible solution for that or at least a good plugin that works?
I found several plugins to do that, but id like to know if someone can recommend one of them.

If its possible id like to use the JQuery-Ui theme to style my scrollbar but the biggest problem i got is that i dont know the actual height of the content container so all the plugins i found cant work dynamic.

Thx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add css style to hide scrollbar:`overflow:hidden;`
[Sample example](http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/hide_scrollbar.cfm)

Is this what youre looking for?
Also take a look at: [jquery-custom-scrollbar-plugins](http://www.net-kit.com/jquery-custom-scrollbar-plugins/)

Comment: thanks for your fast reply!
no i need the scroll function but the standart-scrollbar is ugly as hell ^^
ill take a look to your link now

Comment: i saw most of them already except this one -> http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/ it says that it can be set to auto for the height, so exactly what i need, cause my container is dynamic depending on the screen size and resolution... 

I will try this one now and reply if its working

Comment: @pwittke You're welcome. I also looked at this plugin, and think it is pretty cool one. Glad I could help.